# Renaming duplicate variables in SAS or R

Tags: r, sas, renaming

I am trying to write a code to create a new column that will label a corresponding compound with a number. I have compounds that are repeated in a list and I need those to be labeled with the same number but a letter to separate the compounds. I have no idea how to code this. Thank you, Example below:
What currently have:

```
Fructose 1
Maltose  2
Sucrose  3
Sucrose  4
```

What want:

```
    Fructose 1
    Maltose 2
    Sucrose 3
    Sucrose 3b
```

I cannot label each compound by hand because I have such a large dataset.

Comment: Could you please post an example of what you have and what to want to clarify?

Comment: So instead of labeling each compound with a different number like:         1 (-)-Carvone
2 (-)-Glyceollin I
3 (-)-Hygroline
4 (-)-Jasmonic acid
5 (-)-Jasmonic acid
6 (-)-Jasmonic acid
7 (-)-Jasmonic acid
8 (-)-Jasmonic acid
9 (-)-Limonene
10 (-)-Limonene
 I want this:                                                                                                 1 (-)-Carvone
2 (-)-Glyceollin I
3 (-)-Hygroline
4 (-)-Jasmonic acid
4b (-)-Jasmonic acid
4c (-)-Jasmonic acid
4d (-)-Jasmonic acid
4e (-)-Jasmonic acid
5 (-)-Limonene
5b (-)-Limonene

Comment: I cannot seem to format that into a list like above, sorry.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of writing into the comment section.

Comment: Edited the question to reflect the clarification.

Comment: This is very easy to achieve, but what happens if you have more than 26 dupes in a group? e.i. what are you going to put after `z`? Also, are you aware that your second column will become of class `character` after this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do this with R and the `data.table` package.

First, we will key (and sort) the data by `compound`. Then, we will create our own index and add letters to its dupes (though not sure how you want to handle groups larger than 26)

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df), compound)[, indx := as.character(.GRP), by = compound]
df[duplicated(df), indx := paste0(indx, letters[seq_len(.N)])]
df
#    compound number indx
# 1: Fructose      1    1
# 2:  Maltose      2    2
# 3:  Sucrose      3    3
# 4:  Sucrose      4   3a
```

Comment: I have no compounds with more than 26 reads, so that will not be a problem. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution to your question:

1. Create a **custom format** to map {1} -> {b}, {2} -> {c} etc.
2. **Sort** the dataset you have by the carbohydrate column.
3. Use the interval variable **First.Carbohydrate** which will be equal to 1 if this is the first instance of the carbohydrate.
4. Use a **counter** to keep track of the number of duplicate values.
5. Now use the custom format to **convert your count of duplicates** to the alphnumeric suffix, through the put function: put(counter, customFormat.)

You can read about [by-group data step processing here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000761931.htm) to improve your SAS skills.

Here is complete working example below:

```
    data have;
        length Carb $10; 
        input Carb;
        datalines;
    Fructose
    Maltose 
    Sucrose 
    Sucrose 
    Sucrose 
    Pasta   
    Pasta   
    Rice   
    Rice 
    Rice
    Quinoa
    Bread
    ;

    proc format;
        value dupFormat
        1 = 'b'
        2 = 'c'
        3 = 'd'
        ;
    run;

    proc sort data=have;
        by Carb;
    run;

    data want(keep=Carb Number);
        length Carb $10;
        length Number $3;

        set have;
        by Carb;

        /* nCarbs is the number of distinct carbs written so far */
        if _n_=1 then nCarbs = 0;  

        if first.Carb then do;
            nCarbs+1;
            count_dup = 0; /* the number of duplicate records for the current cab */
            Number = left(put(nCarbs,3.)); 
        end;
        else do;
            count_dup+1;
            Number = cats(put(nCarbs,3.), put(count_dup, dupFormat.));
        end;
    run;

    proc print data=want;
    run;
```

Answer (score 0):

using @jaamor's data, you could do this in base r

```
x <- c('Fructose','Maltose','Sucrose','Sucrose')
x <- c('Fructose','Maltose','Sucrose','Sucrose','Sucrose','Pasta',
       'Pasta','Rice','Rice','Rice','Quinoa','Bread')
y <- gsub('a', '', letters[ave(seq_along(x), x, FUN = seq_along)])

data.frame(x = x, y = paste0(cumsum(!duplicated(x)), y))

#           x  y
# 1  Fructose  1
# 2   Maltose  2
# 3   Sucrose  3
# 4   Sucrose 3b
# 5   Sucrose 3c
# 6     Pasta  4
# 7     Pasta 4b
# 8      Rice  5
# 9      Rice 5b
# 10     Rice 5c
# 11   Quinoa  6
# 12    Bread  7
```